What is the translation of "to do air quotes" in French?
Example:

I'm doing air quotes as I say this.

Meaning:

a pair of quotation marks gestured by raising and flexing the index and middle fingers, used to indicate that what is being said is ironic or mocking

What is the translation of "to do air quotes" in French?


Google Translate says: "Je fais des citations aériennes pendant que je dis cela."
https://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=air+quotes returns no results.


See https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/31075/in-french-how-do-you-say-air-quotes

This question is similar to: In French, how do you say "air quotes"?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@livresque thanks, air quotes = entre guillemets. But what is the translation of "to do air quotes" in French? (perhaps entre guillemets is the only option for that too)

Bref tu cherches un verbe, pas grave !  C'est le verbe qui fait la phrase après tout (ben plus ou moins, un peu, beaucoup, parfois pas du tout).

Wikipedia propose une traduction1 : Geste des guillemets. Cependant je pense qu'elle est peu utilisée et j'ai plus souvent entendu, ou lu,  guillemets avec les doigts.
To do air quotes → faire des guillemets avec ses doigts.

Stop aux guillemets avec les doigts.
On connaît tous quelqu’un qui a cette manie agaçante de faire des guillemets avec ses doigts quand il parle.
(Le Monde, 04/04/2016)


c'est quoi cette manie des "guillemets avec les doigts"
(Site de TF1, 21/04/2021)

On trouvera d'autres exemples de « faire des guillemets avec les doigts » à l'aide d'un moteur de recherche.
J'ai trouvé un article plus ancien, qui date probablement de l'époque où le geste était encore peu répandu en France, et où il est décrit plus que nommé. Cet article qui s'intitule « Adoptez un geste "made in US" », nous montre que c'est un geste qui a été importé d'Outre-Atlantique. Je pense que ce geste est plus courant de nos jours.

Commencez, pour vous exprimer sur les sujets qui fâchent, par lever les deux avant-bras et recourber simultanément l'index et le majeur de chaque main en dessinant des guillemets imaginaires pour figurer toutes les précautions rendues nécessaires par le "politically correct". (Le Point,  26/02/2013)


1 Il suffit de changer la langue pour avoir les articles dans différentes langues.

Il y a quelque qui me gêne un peu dans la question elle-même - elle semble sous-entendre, ou être fondée sur la prémisse qu'il doit y avoir une traduction pour cette expression, et même "la" traduction. Or on sait bien que les langues peuvent refléter des aspects de la culture qui ne vont pas être automatiquement traduisibles par un mot ou une expression exactement équivalente. On semble être dans ce cas de figure ici - même en 2021, comme le montre la citation de TF1, cette manifestation culturelle US n'était pas encore adoptée en France - donc a priori "intraduisible", sauf par périphrase.

Dans le Wiktionnaire : « Guillemet aérien »
Dans le film Les Chèvres du Pentagone (The Men Who Stare at Goats, 2009), à 32:26 : « Guillemets en l'air ».
Il faut noter que ce signe a été créé pour mimer les guillemets anglais ("…" ou “…”) qui n'ont pas la même forme que les guillemets français (« … ») ou d'Asie de l'Est (「…」ou 『…』), donc à moins d'avoir la référence anglophone, ça n'a pas beaucoup de sens.
